# HOW TO updatedata will have date ,i.e's update_date column ssis

Tags: ssis

insert and update data
we will have 2 columns Insert_date and Update_Date.these two columns we will create derived column only (ETL columns) .insert the data first time insert_date column we will appear by using of getdate() function in derived column.but when im update the data 1 or 2 or 3...columns the updated_date column will having null can any one tell me the way to do. Readymade scd component and also lookup an oledb commend model case........

please provide the solution..........friends.

Answer (score 0):

In SSIS, you can do an UPDATE with the OLEDB Command transformation.

Comment: ya but date column issue .when im update only one column that column will reflect updatedate , but all columns updatedate will showing.....

Comment: I'm sorry, can you get a native English speaker to help you reword your comment?   I have no idea what you're trying to say.

Comment: i have two Etl or system generated columns (inserted date and updated date). lookup and OLEDB Command transformation use to perform insert and update . when we insert data first time the "insert date " column date will appear and "updated date" column will shown NULL. next any changes will happen i.es update the data that particular row  "updated date"  column will shown date .

Comment: Ok, so what is the issue?